# How to calculate mean values for a particular column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has values of type: `object`. Dataframe also contains `NaN` values. I want to ignore `NaN` values and for all the remaining values in the column, I want to calculate the mean.

Mean is calculated as follows:
Upperbound value = 30
Lowerbound value = 0

(Upperbound and lowerbound are fixed and all values need to be calculated wrt to them.)

So,

- for '>20', mean = (20+30)/2 = 25
- for '>1', mean = (30+1)/2=15.5
- for '<5', mean = (5+0)/2 = 2.5
- for '<10', mean = (10+0)/2 = 5

Dataframe:

```
column1
>20
NaN
<5
12
>1
<10
NaN
8
```

**Note:** Above values in the column are strings and I want to convert it to numerical value.

Final converted dataframe should be:

```
column1
25
NaN
2.5
12
15.5
5
NaN
8
```

Note: Above values like 8 and 12 are not converted I only want to convert those values which are prefixed with either > or < remaining values just need to be converted to numerical from the string value.

Comment: Are those the only 4 numeric values in your column?

Comment: There is no way to understand where do your numbers come from. Please include an example of what your data is. Also, it looks like you're calculating an average based on certain conditions, what are they?

Comment: @Yuca My upperbound and lowerbound values are fixed and the column has almost 18k rows. So the data which I have shown in question is just a subset of it.

Comment: @gaganso No the column has 18k rows and all values are strings which I need to convert them to numerical values.

Comment: upperbound and lowerbound for what? you don't have to include your entire dataset, just the first 5 rows otherwise it's hard to understand the problem

Comment: @Yuca Check edited question.

Comment: @gaganso Check edited question

Comment: Why downvote ? I have explained properly what I have and what I want ?

Comment: Your question does not meet the criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Yuca What else example do you need. Example is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code applies a custom function that checks the first character of each element and calculates the average based on that.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
upper = 30
lower = 0

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['>20',np.NaN,'<5','12','>1','<10',np.NaN,'8']})
def avg(val):
    if val is not np.NaN:
        char = val[0]
        if char == '>':
            res = (float(val[1:])+upper)/2
        elif char == '<':
            res = (float(val[1:])+lower)/2
        else:
            res = float(val)
        return res

print(df["col1"].apply(avg))
```

Output:

```
0    25.0
1     NaN
2     2.5
3    12.0
4    15.5
5     5.0
6     NaN
7     8.0
```

Comment: Instead of converting NaN values (missing values) to strings we can add if statement to check if `val !=NaN`

Comment: @stonerock, yeah. That's better.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and easy to understand thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better way, but this works too:

```
df['num'] = df.column1.str.extract('(\d+)')
df['sign'] = df.column1.str.extract('([<>])').fillna('=')

def get_avg(row):
    if not row.num:
        return row.num
    elif row.sign == '>':
        return (int(row.num)+30)/2
    elif row.sign == '>':
        return (int(row.num)+0)/2
    else:
        return row.num

df['avg'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_avg(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  column1 sign  num   avg
0     >20    >   20    25
1     NaN    =  NaN   NaN
2      <5    <    5     5
3      12    =   12    12
4      >1    >    1  15.5
5     <10    <   10    10
6     NaN    =  NaN   NaN
7       8    =    8     8
```

Comment: @stonerock, try it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to calculate your "custom average" then call apply on your column.

```
x = np.array([['>20'],[np.NaN],['<5'],['>1'],['<10'],[np.NaN]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["column1"])
def myFunc(content, up, low):
    try:
        if content.isnumeric(): return float(content)
        return {
            '>': (float(content[1:])+up)/2,
            '<': (float(content[1:])+low)/2
        }[content[0]]
    except:
        return np.nan

df["avg"] = df.column1.apply(lambda x: myFunc(x, up=30, low=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` to assign the value you want to average with. And then you can average, after converting column1 to a number.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lt = df[df.column1.notnull()].column1.str.contains('<')
gt = df[df.column1.notnull()].column1.str.contains('>')

conds = [lt, gt, ~(lt | gt)]
choice = [0, 30, pd.to_numeric(df[df.column1.notnull()].column1, errors='coerce')]

df.loc[df.column1.notnull(), 'column2'] = np.select(conds, choice)
df['column1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.column1.str.replace('<|>', ''))

df['Avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2   Avg
0     20.0     30.0  25.0
1      NaN      NaN   NaN
2      5.0      0.0   2.5
3     12.0     12.0  12.0
4      1.0     30.0  15.5
5     10.0      0.0   5.0
6      NaN      NaN   NaN
7      8.0      8.0   8.0
```